# Call MKStoreManager (iPhone) every time

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I want to call `MKStoreManager` every time when i came to in app purchase view so that i can fetch the updated price from iTunes.

But as noticed if i call `[MKStoreManager sharedManager]` once then it will never call again because it is not nil next time.

If i forcefully set `nil` to `_sharedManager` then it is crashing at here:

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:[SKPayment paymentWithProduct:product]];
```

How can i call [MKStoreManager sharedManager] every time in order to get updated values?

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: yes i did @ medvedNick

Comment: can you please describe how?

Comment: I hope you are using a shared class object for in app, like mkstoremanager shared class? by creating a shared object? I did by setting nil to the shared object every time i have to use that class, issue was when i have done this thing is once my shared object gets allocated it never goes to the init method again as this is the concept of shared object i guess to initialize only once. Just try to set the shared object nil whenever you want to fetch the updated products details.Just try this and let me know if its working or not, feel free to ask.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I find a more consistent way to fetch info  every time I want to. There is a private method -requestProductData in  MKStoreManager, I placed its signature to .h file and now I can call it whenever I want to get updated prices. Thanks!

Comment: Great, atleast your task is done.